# Copying a column of data from one table to another in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, sql-update

I have the following setup:

Table1:

```
latdouble
3
4
5
1
6
2
6
9
```

Table2:

```
time    latdouble(type double)    latvarchar(type varchar)   
2:00                              3
3:00                              4
4:00                              5
5:00                              1
6:00                              6
7:00                              2
8:00                              6
9:00                              9
```

Basically latdouble in Table1 is in the correct order and I would like to copy the values into Table2 as they are, the result should be:

Table2:

```
time    latdouble(type double)    latvarchar(type varchar)   
2:00    3                         3
3:00    4                         4
4:00    5                         5
5:00    1                         1
6:00    6                         6
7:00    2                         2
8:00    6                         6
9:00    9                         9
```

As far as I'm aware I need to use a command similar to:

```
update Table2 set latdouble = (select latdouble from Table1)
```

However I get the following error:

```
ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

I'm sure there's a simple fix but I can't figure it out,

Thanks,
James

UPDATE: Let me just explain how this came about. Table 2 originally looked like:

Table2:

```
time    latvarchar(type varchar)   
2:00    3                         
3:00    4                         
4:00    5                         
5:00    1                         
6:00    6                         
7:00    2                         
8:00    6                         
9:00    9
```

I added the latdouble(type double) column to Table2.

I then created a new table called Table1 which contains a column called latdouble(type double). I used the following command to cast latvarchar from Table2 and copy it into Table1:

```
insert into Table1 (latdouble) select cast(latvarchar as double precision) from Table2
```

And now I want to copy the values back from Table1 latdouble to Table2 latdouble. The reason I did this is to cast the values from latvarchar to double and save them in latdouble without having to create a temporary copy of the whole of Table2 as it is a very large table with a few indexes.

Comment: Does Table1 have a sortable primary key?  If not, then the 'order' you are seeing is merely convenience on the part of the engine.  There's nothing stopping it from displaying it in any random order on future queries...  Add and populate some column to Table1 to indicate the sort sequence you want, at which point a solution will be possible.

Comment: No it doesn't have a primary key but please can you see the update I have added which explains how this situation came about. Does the method I've chosen to create Table1 mean that the 'order' is not just convenience?

Comment: A table without a primary key is (near to) meaningless.

Comment: It was just supposed to be a temporary table hence I didn't see the need for any keys, but obviously if I add a primary key I can then use that to copy the data to table 1 based on the key.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding correctly, there's no need to use Table1 at all.  You can simply set the `latdouble` value for each row in place using UPDATE:

```
UPDATE Table2 SET latdouble = cast(latvarchar as double precision);
```

**UPDATE**

To do this incrementally, I can think of 2 options.

**Option 1.** (Quick and Dirty)

```
UPDATE Table2 
SET latdouble = cast(latvarchar as double precision)
WHERE tKey IN (SELECT tKey FROM Table2 WHERE latdouble IS NULL LIMIT 10000);
```

Run this many times until no rows are updated anymore (which means no `latdouble` fields are NULL)

**Option 2.** (Use a cursor and commit incrementally)

Following the method in [this article](http://www.kennygorman.com/wordpress/?p=245), you can run this python script:

```
#!/home/postgres/python/bin/python
#
# incremental commits
# 2008 kcg

import psycopg2
import time

# vars
incremental_commit_size=10000   # number of rows
throttle_time=0         # seconds

connectstr="host=localhost dbname=postgres user=postgres port=5432"
handle=psycopg2.connect(connectstr)
cursor=handle.cursor()
cursor2=handle.cursor()
sql="select tKey from table2"
cursor.execute(sql)

while 1:

 output = cursor.fetchmany(incremental_commit_size)

 if not output:
  break
 for row in output:

   # update table
   sql="update table2 set latdouble = cast(latvarchar as double precision) where tKey = %s"
   cursor2.execute(sql,([row[0]]))

 #commit, invoked every incremental commit size
 handle.commit()
 time.sleep(throttle_time)

handle.commit()
```

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't this create a temporary copy of Table2 in PostgreSQL? In which case the temporary table would take up a further 100GB...

Comment: Nope, it doesn't create anything temporary at all. It simply updates the existing row with the new values.  Do you have a specific reason to believe otherwise?  I haven't ever come across such a concern when using a simple UPDATE statement...

Comment: To make the point stronger - if `latdouble` already exists on your Table2 as `double precision`, then the database has already allocated the necessary space for it.  So an update on this column shouldn't make your DB grow at all.  It certainly shouldn't require any temp tables (aside from transaction-level that can't be avoided in any statement you use).

Comment: Yes I ran similar update commands (can't be sure if they were exactly the same) on the same table to try and solve this problem and I kept getting an out of space error. So I then researched on the internet and read about update creating a temporary copy of the table which it then applies changes to before committing the changes back and deleting the temporary table.

Comment: Can you post a link to this information?  It doesn't sound correct to me, but you never know...

Comment: I am trying this command now, thanks for the help! Just to note I do have 16GB free space which should be plenty for the transaction-level temporary items, so hopefully it works...

Comment: To be honest I have closed the tabs now and I have no idea which pages I saw this on sorry!

Comment: If transaction-level artifacts are causing too much bloat, you can avoid this by doing the update incrementally (10K rows at a time for example), but that's probably overkill for this case.

Comment: I think my computer is going to run out of memory again, I'm down to 5.75GB from 16GB after 2850 seconds. Please could you explain to me how I can run the update incrementally?

Comment: Does your Table2 have a primary key?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I'm trying the first method as I understand it better however I am getting the following error `ERROR: syntax error at or near "10000"`

Comment: Just managed to work out the PostgreSQL syntax `UPDATE Table2 
SET latdouble = cast(latvarchar as double precision)
WHERE tKey BETWEEN 9894 AND 19893` I can do this for each 10,000 block segment as I know tkey starts at 9894 and increments.

Comment: Oops, I forgot that postgres uses LIMIT and not TOP - fixed

Comment: solution 2 works also for a commit every line using ```incremental_commit_size=1```